# Use the same color palette for different projects

Tags: python, colors, palette, color-palette

I've been looking for a way to keep a unified selection of colors that I can access in different projects and use with different frameworks for a while.

The idea is to define a color palette such as:

```
palette = {
    "orange": "#ce8964",
    "yellow": "#eaf27c",
    "green": "#71b48d",
    "blue": "#454ade"
}
```

Which translates to these colors:

[image]

But then instead of re-defining these tuples everytime I want to use the palette, I wanted to be able to load them from somewhere when needed with one line of code like `palette = load_colors()`.

This would be useful since I can't remember the values of the colors I used in previous projects, so I find myself frequently searching old scripts for them.

When I load the colors, they should also change format to be understood by the framework I'm using:

In tkinter colors are hex strings:

```
palette["orange"] = '#ce8964'
canvas.create_line(0, 0, 100, 100, fill=palette["orange"])
```

In pygame they are RGB tuples:

```
palette["orange"] = (206, 137, 100)
pygame.draw.line(win, palette["orange"], (0, 0), (100, 100))
```

But I wanted to have `orange` be universally understood so that it can be used for any targeted framework.

Is there a way to implement a system like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[colorir](https://colorir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) exists for this very purpose.

A palette is a collection of named colors, in this case:

```
from colorir import *
palette = Palette(
    name="my_palette",
    orange"="#ce8964",
    yellow"="#eaf27c",
    green"="#71b48d",
    blue"="#454ade"
)
```

The palette can then be saved with `palette.save()`.

And later be loaded (even from a different project) with `palette = Palette.load("my_palette")`.

The saving-loading process is entirely managed by `colorir`, so you don't have to deal with any files or directories.

Colors are then accessed as such:

```
>>> palette.orange
Hex('#ce8964')
```

And they can be provided directly to frameworks (no need to convert to string before):

```
# Tkinter
win = Tk()
win.config(bg=palette.orange)  # Supply orange as background color
win.mainloop()
```

[image]

To ensure that `palette` is compatible with other frameworks, you just have to specify the desired format when loading it:

```
>>> palette = Palette.load("my_palette", PYGAME_COLOR_FORMAT)
>>> palette.orange  # This can be passed to pygame functions now
sRGB(206, 137, 100)
```

`colorir` also has features like swatching palettes (to see what they look like), creating palettes from gradients, and many more things that make choosing a color palette for a project much easier.

---

**Disclaimer:** I'm the developer of `colorir`.

Comment: You could mention in your Answer how Users can import your Library in their Project or where they can download/copy it "locally", `from colorir import *` will never work if that Library was not first imported, either from your Repository or copied locally...